# Application Behavior returns 404 on working pages

Tags: python, django

I have configured

```
handler404 = 'myapp.views.error404'
```

Definition:

```
def error404(request):
        print "404 - Page"
        return render(request, request.LANGUAGE_CODE + "/404.html" , status=404 )
```

in URL dispatcher - which works fine. But I see 404 - Page message in my terminal for every request however Im getting redirected to 404.html only when I type wrong URL.

any significant reason for this behavior.

Comment: I tried your code in a new project and I can't reproduce the problem. Are you sure you are not requesting a nonexistent resource in your template HTML code, causing a separate 404 error on every request?

Comment: and even if you are not requesting anything, browser might still ask for favicon etc. try changing debug line to 'print "404 - Page", request.path' and you will know

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't read comments (the partial response has been given):

The 404 error can be trigger by another thing than the page request: broken images, favicon, css, js... For example, if you request `/static/my_file.css`.
If your web server fails to serves a static files and redirect the request to your Django application it'll fail too, and returns the error page.

A way to see why the handle is called is to display the `request.path` of the current request, to see which URL is called:

```
def error404(request):
    print "404 - URL: ", request.path
    return render(request, request.LANGUAGE_CODE + "/404.html" , status=404)
```

It's common when you're deploying a project and you have some issues with static files :)